# Selecting distinct rows and the number of their occurances

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table that contains the order contents for orders that have been replaced.

**Table order_contents**

```
contentid(PK) orderid productid
1             3       150
2             3       152
3             4       150
4             4       150
5             4       160
6             4       162
```

I'm trying to create an SQL search that would display distinct products and then the quantity that is being ordered.

I'm now here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT productid FROM order_contents WHERE orderid = '4';
```

Output:

```
productid
150
160
162
```

This displays the distinct products which is great, but now I still need the other column to display how many of the product has been ordered. I've tried doing count(*) and similar, but then the results consist of one row only.

What I need:

```
productid     quantity
150           2
160           1
162           1
```

This needs to be fixed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT productid, < ??? > as quantity FROM order_contents WHERE orderid = '4';
```

Help would be appreciated. Maybe I made a word search, but there didn't seem to be any duplicates of this type of question.

**UPDATE:**
Ok, I admit that I feel a bit foolish since the answer clearly was to use GROUP BY. This is what I was looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT productid, count(productid) as quantity FROM order_contents WHERE orderid = '4' GROUP BY productid;
```

Comment: Are you trying to do a GROUP BY? (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/group-by/)

Comment: Wow, do I feel like a simpleton. In reality my query was significantly more complex than that, but yes, by fiddling with the GROUP BY -feature I managed to get the query working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you missed a GROUP BY clause. And to make an awesome SQL you could use GROUP_CONCAT, check this out:

**The data:**

```
alemonitor-> select * from order_contents;
+-----------+---------+-----------+------+
| contentid | orderid | productid | qty  |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------+
|         2 |       3 |       150 |    5 |
|         4 |       3 |       152 |   93 |
|         6 |       4 |       150 |   50 |
|         8 |       4 |       150 |   69 |
|        10 |       4 |       160 |   96 |
|        12 |       4 |       162 |   74 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**The Solution:**

```
alemonitor-> SELECT productid, GROUP_CONCAT(qty) FROM order_contents GROUP BY productid;
+-----------+-------------------+
| productid | GROUP_CONCAT(qty) |
+-----------+-------------------+
|       150 | 5,50,69           |
|       152 | 93                |
|       160 | 96                |
|       162 | 74                |
+-----------+-------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Enjoy it!

Alex

Comment: please, pay attention that you can use syntax highlighter in editor - `{}`